# Adding switzerland cran mirror for R in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: r

I've got an error while trying to add the R cran mirror for Switzerland to the sources.list file (http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/), even though I followed the instructions from page http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/ (I'm running Ubuntu 13.04) I really can't find what I'm doing wrong... here are my steps:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then, in the source.list file, I added a line like that, at the very end:

```
#R repositories switzerland 
http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
```

then, save and exit and the error appears when typing the sudo apt-get update command:

```
sudo apt-get update 
E: Type 'http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu' is not known on line 60 in
source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

why?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I think you can't mix R repos and Ubuntu repos. When doing a command such as `install.packages()` _from within R_, it should prompt you to pick a repo. There you can choose CH.

Comment: that's ok, I just followed the instruction on the R webpage

Answer (score 3):

héhé found the answer: just adding 'deb' before the link:

```
deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
```

However, people can simply install directly by running from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

it's much easier and worked for me (R installed and works well)